# Sound broken on Chrome

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, audio

So my sound for Google Chrome browser isn't working. I have Windows 8, and when I try to watch any youtube video, no sound plays, though the video does. I launched Internet Explorer, and watched a video, and I could hear the sound.

Can anybody identify the problem, and tell me a fix for this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Did this start happening recently? Have you installed the Win8.1 Preview by any chance? Did you try reinstalling Chrome?

Comment: Problem fixed! It turns out that my USB connector was running on some old drivers and didn't support new versions of Chrome.

Comment: You should post that as an answer below with details that will help others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to disable flash and force youtube to render the videos in HTML5.

Go to [youtubes HTML 5](http://www.youtube.com/html5) page to try without flash.

Comment: It turns out that Chrome does work with my speakers, but when I use my headset it doesn't work. I use Chrome at work, and I need my headset to communicate with people online. My headset works with everything else.

Answer (score 0):

The drivers for the headset were outdated, and I was using a version not detected by Windows in Device Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Check the little audio speaker icon in the taskbar (next to Clock) and see if the separate audio level controller for Chrome is not set to Volume level 0. This was the solution for me, when I was trying several other methods like disabling plugins etc.